# CORS error: Turning CSV file into Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, csv

I am trying convert a CSV file into a javascript array. In the CSV file, all of the values are on separate lines. Anyway, I found this piece of code in another post on Stackoverflow to turn such a file into an array:

```
var adressesList = []

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "Filepath",
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        processData(data);
      }
    });
  });

  function processData(allText) {
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    for (var i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
      adressesList.push(allTextLines[i]);
    }
  }
```

I have tried this but I keep getting an error saying that I am not allowed to access the file (it is local on my computer in the same folder as the code).

This is the error I see:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'filepat' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

GET filepath net::ERR_FAILED
```

How could I solve it? I saw that you could put the file on a server. But, shouldn't there just be an easy way to do it locally?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need this as a one time solution running locally, you might find it easier to load and process this file via [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications).

Example:

```js
function handleFiles(files) {
  getAsText(files[0])
}

function getAsText(fileToRead) {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsText(fileToRead)
  reader.onload = (event) => processData(event.target.result)
}

function processData(allText) {
  console.log(allText)
  // do your processing below
  var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/)
  for (var i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
   adressesList.push(allTextLines[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" accept=".csv">
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that and give some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is static (you write it once and it stays the same), then you can export it as a constant and won't need to use ajax. See more about how to do that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

If the file is dynamic and will change over time, you'll need to put it on a webserver you can request the file from, often called an "endpoint". If you're on a different domain (say the server is on foo.com and your website is on bar.com) you'll need to add permission on the server settings to allow requests from other domains.

Comment: The file is static, the values never have to be changed.

Comment: Yup, then exporting the csv is the way to go.